# Help with finding integral

Tags: integration

I've been trying for an embarrassingly long time to figure this one out.  It looks like it should crack under integration by parts and integration by substitution, but I am having trouble with it.  Any pointers?

$$\int {\exp(a \sqrt{x^2 + b} ) \over \sqrt{x^2+b} } dx$$

Comment: You're sure there's no x in the numerator?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha hasn't found result in the terms of standard mathematical functions..

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+%7B%5Cexp%28a+%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2+%2B+b%7D+%29+%5Cover+%5Csqrt%7Bx%5E2%2Bb%7D+%7D+dx) says it has no expression in elementary terms.

Comment: This was part of a larger homework problem in a random signals class where I was trying to prove/disprove independence of two RVs with a joint pdf that looks similar to the integral above.  Apparently solving it by directly using integration is not the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special case $a=1,b=0$ simplifies to

$$\int \frac{e^x}{x} \, dx$$

Which is known as the [Exponential Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) where no closed form is known. Therefore your integral has no general closed form either.

Note: By closed form I mean that it is not expressible in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: ...I consider the exponential integral as a closed form expression in its own right. Better to say that the exponential integral is not expressible in terms of the elementary functions...

Comment: I added a note to clarify what I mean, although if you consider $\text{Ei(x)}$ to be a closed form expression you could define every integral as a function and call it closed form :-)

Comment: Sure, but another part of my "closed-form" schtick is that there's a whole corpus of identities relating it to a lot of other functions. ;) You don't have that with, say, $\int u^u \mathrm du$.

Answer (score 1):

The natural substitution is to let $u=a\sqrt{x^2+b}$ so that $du=\frac{ax}{\sqrt{x^2+b}}$ and $x^2=\frac{u^2}{a^2}-b$. Our integral then is

$$\int \frac{e^u}{\sqrt{u^2-ba^2}} du.$$  However, there is no way to deal with something of this form.  Are you sure that you are not missing a  multiple of $x$?  In other words, I think the question should be to integrate $$\int \frac{x\exp(a\sqrt{x^2+b})}{\sqrt{x^2+b}}dx$$ because then it gives $$\frac{1}{a}e^{a\sqrt{x^2+b}}$$ as the anti derivative.